# Can I add "Smartypants" to restructuredText?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I use restructuredText, and I like what smartypants does for Markdown. Is there a way to enable the same thing for restructuredText?

Comment: Looks like you were cut off mid-transmission... :P

Comment: @Nick: Thanks. I don't even know what I was trying to say there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Martelli says, smartyPants is what I need. However, I was looking for a little more detailed info on how to use it. So here's a Python script that reads the file named in the first command line argument, converts it to HTML, using Pygments for `sourcecode`, and then passses it through smartypants for prettifying.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'docutils==0.5','rst2html.py'
"""
A minimal front end to the Docutils Publisher, producing HTML.
"""

try:
    from ulif.rest import directives_plain
    from ulif.rest import roles_plain
    from ulif.rest import pygments_directive

    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
except:
  pass

from docutils.core import publish_doctree, publish_from_doctree
from smartypants import smartyPants
import sys


description = ('Personal docutils parser with extra features.')

doctree = publish_doctree(file(sys.argv[1]).read())
result = publish_from_doctree(doctree, writer_name='html')
result = smartyPants(result)
print result
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [smartypants.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartypants/1.6.0.3)?  I don't know how well it's implemented, much less how well it works for your specific use cases, but it does seem to target exactly your goal, unicode-ification of some ascii constructs (however, it runs on HTML, so I guess you'd run it *after* `restructuredText` or whatever other "producer of HTML" component).

If that doesn't work well for you, a user has submitted a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/issues/detail?id=42) to python-markdown2 which he calls "this SmartyPants patch" -- it's been accepted and since a month ago it's part of the current source tree of python-markdown2 ([r259](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/source/detail?r=259) or better).  That may offer smoother sailing (e.g. if you just get and built python-markdown2 as a read-only [svn tree](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/source/checkout)).  Or, you could wait for the next downloadable release (there hasn't been one since May and this patch was accepted in mid-July), but who knows when that'll happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.10 (2012-12-16) there is native support: you can tell Docutils to "educate" quotes with the [smart-quotes](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.html#smart-quotes) setting.